# Magento Sorting By Bestsellers using Amasty Extension

Tags: magento, sorting, module

I have installed Amasty's Improved Sorting module and I get 404s for all the urls in the extension. The backend all appears to work fine. Sorting works for items not in their extension.

Why are we getting 404s?

Any thoughts much appreciated as the support at Amasty will only help if they can access our servers which we cannot offer.

Urls like this fail:

http://local.ourdomain.com/magento/store/music/sort-by/bestsellers/sort-direction/desc.html

http://local.ourdomain.com/magento/store/ajax/layered-navigation/catalogsearch/result/index/q/jack/requested-url/search/sort-by/most_viewed/sort-direction/desc?q=jack

http://local.ourdomain.com/magento/store/ajax/layered-navigation/catalog/category/view/id/10/requested-url/music/sort-by/bestsellers/sort-direction/desc.html

These work:

http://local.ourdomain.com/magento/store/ajax/layered-navigation/catalog/category/view/id/10/requested-url/music/sort-by/name/sort-direction/asc.html

http://local.ourdomain.com/magento/store/ajax/layered-navigation/catalog/category/view/id/10/requested-url/music/sort-by/price/sort-direction/asc.html

Also ran their conflict checking script and there don't appear to be any conflicts

Answer (score 0):

As far as you see the urls are changed by some extension, because the magento default urls use query params.

Most probably the third party module rewrites/changes logic of app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Toolbar.php class and it results in incorrect behavior.